# How to handle import that changes by Java version, and compile over multiple versions

Tags: java, inheritance

I've got Java code that is subclassing `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextFieldSkin`. (Yes, I know that I'm supposed to beware using `sun.com.*`.) Consider me appropriately chastized.

With Java 9, this class is now in the mainstream, available as `javafx.scene.control.skin.TextFieldSkin`. I'd like my code to be buildable on Java 8 and higher. But since the code has moved, I need different imports depending on the version.

I can't do [conditional inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32822969/490329) based on Java version, because it [happens at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33176787/490329). I'm using Maven, so I could use the [Munge plugin](https://sonatype.github.io/munge-maven-plugin/) to do conditional compilation; that appears as though it will work, though it will cause annoying errors to be flagged in my development environment in realtime as I code because the import in either case will be enclosed in comments away.

What's the right way to handle this?

Comment: if you are using ant you could have different build files per version and scripts to "compensate" for the changes

Comment: Just move problematic parts to 2 different maven modules and put them in profiles activated based on jdk version

Comment: Thanks, @rkosegi. I'll give it a try.

Comment: for instance team developing postgres jdbc uses java preprocessor to build variants for different classes, also it is possible to use java preprocessor to build applications for jep-238 https://github.com/raydac/jep-238-jcp-example